# VBA using like operator with wildcards

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare address data. My current macro compares two columns and inputs "Dropped Data" when they don't match. The problem is that a large number of these values haven't been dropped but integrated into another cell. I want to change my macro to be able to find the missing value using VBA's like operator. For example it would find "Bldg 3" in "9825 Spectrum Dr Bldg 3". I was able to get this code from looking around the web and I'm not sure what range `Range("C65536")` is selecting.

Edit: I see people are suggesting I use the Instr function which does seem to do what I want to do. I'm not sure how I would get it to work in my macro/ get it to reference the correct cells. It also (from what I understand) returns values equal to the number of characters found. So in the example I gave it would return a value of 6 if you include the space.

```
Sub droppeddata()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
For a = lr To 1 Step -1
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(a, 13).Value) And IsEmpty(Cells(a, 19)) Then
Cells(a, 10).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N"
Cells(a, 11).Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dropped Data"
End If
Next a

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The Range statement is looking for the last used row (lr) in column C by starting at C65536 and jumping upwards.  If you want to find parts of a string inside a cell value, you need to look at the `InStr` function...

Comment: If you just want to check if the cell contains certain characters you could use instr http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-instr-function/ If i've understood the question correctly

Comment: `InStr` tells you if the content you're looking for is in the string (and thus the origin of the name `InStr`). Instead of guessing whether you understand it correctly, you could read the page @Rob linked or read the documentation for the function.

Comment: @RobWhite I did read the page that Rob linked. Thank you everyone for contributing I'll do my best to take it from here unless anyone else would care to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current macro doesn't compare anything the way you want it to, it just checks whether or not two columns are empty.

You haven't been very specific with what you are trying to do, so this code is done with a bit of guess-work:

```
Sub droppeddata()
    Dim lr As Long ' Declare the variable
    lr = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row ' Set the variable
    ' lr now contains the last used row in column C

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For a = lr To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(a, 19)) Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 13).Value, Cells(a, 19).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' If Cells(a, 19) is empty OR
        ' Search Cells(a, 13) for the value contained in Cells(a, 19)
        ' If INSTR returns a match greater than 0, it means the string we're looking for is present
        ' Enter the loop if either condition is true

            ' In this section, avoiding SELECT is preferable. Working directly on the ranges is good.
            With Cells(a, 10)
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = "N"
            End With

            With Cells(a, 11)
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = "Dropped Data"
            End With
        End If
    Next a

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Change the ranges/cells to your need - the current ones aren't meant to work, I merely guessed based on your existing code.